# My ng-model allows duplicates when I don't want it to

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

So I have this drop down menu that allows multiple selections. I am using the ng-model, ng-options, and ng-change clauses. For some reason, I cannot figure out how to prevent pushing a object into the model that is already in there. So I tried to make a 2nd temporary array to push them into and then remove any duplicates but I also couldn't get that to work. Let me explain with my code.

Example objects being pushed into the select object:

```js
[{
  userProfileID: "3f8c553c-3633-4fe9-a007-4346a783450c",
  firstName: 'Austin',
  lastName: 'Hunter',
  email: 'ahunteroutlook.com',
  password: 'admin',
  companyProfileID: "86660a5b-7f61-4238-889d-1cc3087947b9",
  accessLevel: 'admin'
},
{
  userProfileID: "bc579485-95a7-4e8d-bdde-52272923576e",
  firstName: 'Ashley',
  lastName: 'Jeanette',
  email: 'ashleygmail.com',
  password: 'admin',
  companyProfileID: "86660a5b-7f61-4238-889d-1cc3087947b9",
  accessLevel: ''
}]
```

So obviously when I want to check for duplicates, I can just check for multiples of the userProfileID. I got that much..

ng-change function:

```js
$scope.changedDepartment = function(item) {
    $scope.selectUser = [];
 $scope.users = [];
 $scope.tempUsers.length = 0;
   if ($scope.department.length > 0) {
     if (item[0].DepartmentUsers.length > 0) {
      $scope.users.length = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
       for (var j = 0; j < item[i].DepartmentUsers.length; j++) {
         if (profile[0].userProfileID != item[i].DepartmentUsers[j].userProfileID) {
                $scope.tempUsers.push(item[i].DepartmentUsers[j]);
         }
       }
      }
```

(sorry for the formatting, copied and pasted from code and it totally messed with my indentation)

So what is happening here:
The function is seeing that we clicked something in the select box, passes it that item. Then it searches that item for any users inside it and pushes them inside $scope.tempUsers. I need the users to be in $scope.users. So my plan is to go through $scope.tempUsers and remove any duplicates, but I cannot figure out how. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it using this method:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tempUsers.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < $scope.tempUsers.length; j++) {
        if ($scope.tempUsers[i].userProfileID == $scope.tempUsers[j].userProfileID) {
            $scope.tempUsers.splice(j, 1);
        }
    }
    $scope.users.push($scope.tempUsers[i]);
}
```